# Using DataNitro, how do I print a python loop to excel, making sure that after 23 rows are printed, printing moves to the adjacent column?

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

I am using grequest to pull json data from multiple urls. With the help of another user here, I was able to get python to print the results from each url in succession. Now, I want to print those results to excel using DataNitro. Here is the code I have now.

```
import grequests
import json


urls = [
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-1ST&type=both&depth=50',
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-AMP&type=both&depth=50',
    'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-ARDR&type=both&depth=50',
]

requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(requests)

for response in responses:
    Cell("A1").value = "Buy"
    Cell("A2").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A3").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Rate'])
    Cell("A4").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][1]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A5").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][1]['Rate'])
    Cell("A6").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][2]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A7").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][2]['Rate'])
    Cell("A8").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][3]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A9").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][3]['Rate'])
    Cell("A10").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][4]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A11").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][4]['Rate'])
    Cell("A12").value = "Sell"
    Cell("A13").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][0]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A14").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][0]['Rate'])
    Cell("A15").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][1]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A16").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][1]['Rate'])
    Cell("A17").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][2]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A18").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][2]['Rate'])
    Cell("A19").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][3]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A20").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][3]['Rate'])
    Cell("A21").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][4]['Quantity'])
    Cell("A22").value = (response.json()['result']['sell'][4]['Rate'])
    Cell("A23").value = "----"
```

This works just fine, but only if I comment out all but one url, otherwise the results from the first url are overwritten by the results from the second url, an expected result. However, this is not what I want. In the end, I want the results from the first url to print in cells A1:A23, the results from the second to print in cells B1:B23, and the third's to print in cells C1:C23.

Here is what I have tried:

```
for response in responses:
    #print("Buy")
    Quantity = [response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][1]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][2]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][3]['Quantity'],
        response.json()['result']['buy'][4]['Quantity']
]
    Cell("A1:E5").vertical = Quantity
```

(Note: I am only trying the Quantity here).

This does not work because it only prints the first url's results in column A, and it does not move on to column B to print subsequent results. I tried switching `Cell("A1:E5").vertical = Quantity` with `Cell("A1:E5").vertical_range = Quantity`, but python returns the following error:

```
    Cell("A1:E5").vertical_range = Quantity
  File "27\basic_io.py", line 379, in __setattr__
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I was thinking about doing something with my original set up (i.e., using the `Cell("A2").value = (response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'])` type of code), adding something like `i = 0`, and then writing the last print line to read something like `Cell(23,(1+i)).value = "----"` but I could not figure out (mentally) how to make that work. With the `Cell(23,(1+i)).value = "----"` line, it would just print "----" in cell B1, and then it overwrites all the results in column A again, which, again, makes sense when you see what the code is actually doing.

I am at a loss, but I feel like the answer is relatively simple, and I am just missing it. I went through the 9 pages of results on this site that mention DataNitro and https://datanitro.com/docs/: I could not find an answer. I would appreciate any help!

EDIT: I realized that it does not matter that it prints 5 and then moves to the adjacent column. All I need it to do is print all the results to excel without overwriting itself: that can be all results show up in one column, or all results show up in one row.

I have since tried

```
CellRange((1,1),(1,2)).value = [response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'],
response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Rate']
```

But I am running into the same problem, it just overwrites the data from the first url. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `.vertical` instead of `.value`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was using vertical because of something I read in the DataNitro documents, but I cannot seem to find it again. Anyways, when I run `.value` instead of `.vertical`, it does print out the responses, but it puts them all in one cell and encloses them in brackets. If I remove the brackets, it starts to overwrite the values again.

Comment: The right side of the Expression, here `Quantity` have to be a List of Values. May I see the Output of `print(Quantity)`.

Comment: I am not sure if this what you meant, but when I run                                  
`for response in responses: 
    print("Buy") 
    Quantity = [response.json()['result']['buy'][0]['Quantity'],
  response.json()['result']['buy'][1]['Quantity'],
  response.json()['result']['buy'][2]['Quantity'],
  response.json()['result']['buy'][3]['Quantity'],
  response.json()['result']['buy'][4]['Quantity']
]
    print Quantity`

Comment: I get                                                                                                        
`Buy
[1962.60059677, 14.98071233, 58.75801224, 16131.0, 12.86986961]
Buy
[27.58334194, 2636.39735264, 108.56591075, 13262.62025727, 1210.68142649]
Buy
[11058.25577462, 6000.0, 150.0, 139135.18518519, 12261.404]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: Issue(3) is resolved when the entire worksheet is cleared of its data prior to rerunning the script

Rerunning the Script will always Start with `row = 1`. If you want to append Data to existing Sheet set `row = MAX ROW OF OLD DATA +1`.

---

> **Comment**: How would this script change with different JSON structures. Compare bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/… with api.livecoin.net/exchange/order_book?currencyPair=ABN/…

The First is a `list of dict`, the Second is a `list of list`. Use `[0, 1]` as `keys`, for example:

```
# Usage for list
row += json_to_cell('Buy', response.json()['result']['buy'], row, [0, 1])
```

---

> **Comment**: some ... return less than 5 data entries, or sometimes, one URL will not work at all.

Generalized Approach:

```
def json_to_cell(title, _json, start_row, keys):
    values = len(_json)
    if values:
        CellRange((start_row, 1), (start_row, 1)).value = [title]
        start_row += 1

        for row, key in enumerate(keys, start_row):
            rowData = []
            for c in range(0, values):
                rowData.append(_json[c][key])

            CellRange((row, 1), (row, values)).value = rowData
        return len(keys) + 1
    else:
        # Write some Info NO VALUES
        return 0

keys = ['Quantity', 'Rate']
row = 1
for response in responses:
    row += json_to_cell('Buy', response.json()['result']['buy'], row, keys)
    row += json_to_cell('Sell', response.json()['result']['sell'], row, keys)

    CellRange((row, 1), (row, 1)).value = ['----']
    row += 1
```

---

> **Comment**: IndexError: CellRange set to object of wrong lengt

Both, `CellRange` and `len(rowData)`, should be 5.
Add a `print(...`, see below, and show one Output.

Use the following:

```
for row, response in enumerate(responses, 1):
    rowData = []
    for c in range(0, 5):
        rowData.append(response.json()['result']['buy'][c]['Quantity'])

    print( rowData)
    CellRange((row, 1),(row, 5)).value = rowData
```

Comment: When I run that, I get the following error:                                 
 `IndexError: CellRange set to object of wrong length`

Comment: But it does print to the columns. When I change `CellRange ((row, 1), (row, 5)).value = rowData` to `CellRange ((row, 1), (row, 15)).value = rowData` it does print more columns.

Comment: After running: `for row, response in enumerate(responses,1):
    rowData = []
    for c in range(1,5):
        rowData.append(response.json()['result']['buy'][c]['Quantity'])
    print( rowData)
    CellRange((row, 1),(row, 5)).value = rowData`  I get `[1006.14720103, 902.98186853, 79.93646234, 56.27735879]` Sorry if that is not what you meant.

Comment: @Jim: My bad, I overlooked to Start from `0`, must be `range(0, 5)`.

Comment: A few issues with output: (1) it prints out more than 5 results for each url (it prints out every 'buy' 'Quantity' and every 'buy' 'Rate' (same for the 'sell'); (2) it prints out one 'Quantity' and 'Rate' pair and then moves to the next column (this may be intentional, and will work for us, though it differed from the output of your original answer, so I thought I would bring it up); and (3) when a certain number urls are used, some number over three, I can't figure out the exact number, the first url's ouput loses its format. See link for picture of all three issues: https://ibb.co/ksL1Pv

Comment: Issue(3) is resolved when the entire worksheet is cleared of its data prior to rerunning the script.

Comment: Issue(1) is resolved by changing `values = len(_json)` to `values = len(_json[0:5])`. What's nice is that this does not mess up the `#Write some Info NO VALUES` code, like I thought it would. After doing some more research, issue (2) appears to require an overhaul of some core parts of the script, something beyond my capability. Nevertheless, our project can move forward with its current output.

Comment: How would this script change with different JSON structures. Compare https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-1ST&type=both&depth=50 with https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/order_book?currencyPair=ABN/BTC&depth=5     When I try to change the key values, I get `string indices must be integers`. I used http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to help me determine the keys.